# JavaScript .forEach() and .splice() not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to write a simple program to remove vowels and spaces from a string. There is some errant behavior to the following code that I cannot explain.

```
var vowels, testString, splitString, disemvoweled;

vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
testString = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';
splitString = testString.split('');

splitString.forEach(function (char) {
    vowels.forEach(function (vowel) {
      if (char === vowel || char === ' ') {
        splitString.splice(splitString.indexOf(char), 1);
      }
    });
 });

disemvoweled = splitString.toString();
console.log(disemvoweled);  // 't,h,q,i,c,k,b,r,w,n,f,x,j,m,p,d,v,r,t,h,l,z,y,d'
```

In the returned string above, you will see an *i* in the 4th position. Additionally, the *g* for *dog* was not included in the result. Clearly, something is not working as expected. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: `char === vowel` should be: `vowel.indexOf(char) != -1 // in the vowel array`

Comment: I would like to point out that your run time for this is n^2.   it can be done in time: N.  It is not relevant to the question at hand though.

Comment: @Fallenreaper Can you elaborate? I'm not familiar with n^2 vs N.

Comment: mutating the array *while* you are iterating over probably isn't what you mean to do here.

Comment: If you iterate in reverse order it is fine though

Comment: which isn't what `forEach` does. :( [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: you could also try looking into the replace function. Basically var someString = 'test'; someString.replace('e', ''); would remove the 'e' character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't just use `.replace()` to remove vowels and spaces:

```
var testString = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';
var newString = testString.replace(/[aeiou\s]/ig, "");
```

If you then want it a comma separated string, you can do that too:

```
newString = newString.split("").join(",");
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/x3sXW/

Comment: This is the approach that I would suggest.

Comment: This is the best approach to accomplish your goal Evan, and you wouldnt need to write it to be more efficient as i mentioned in the above comment about your code snippet.

Comment: @jfreind00 you can just do:   `newString.split("").toString()` as well.  By default, `toString()` on an array would make it comma seperated.

Comment: based on this runtime test, `toString()` is slightly faster then `join()`.  Test executed in Chrome.  http://jsperf.com/tostring-join

Answer (score 3):

your call to `splice(index, 1)` removes the array element at index, shifting all following indexes by one.

Since this is happening inside the `forEach`-loop, you make the outer loop skip the check of the character following that vowel.

You could use `filter()` instead to avoid mutating the array you are iterating:

```
splitString
  .filter(function(character) { return vowels.indexOf(character) === -1; })
  .toString();
```